# How can I restore the browser button?

Tags: browser, buttons, mi, xiaomi-mi9

For some magical reason, the browser button on the home screen of my Android phone (Xiaomi MI 9 SE, MIUI 10.2) has gone missing. I can't find it!

... how can I restore/recreate it?

Note I'm not talking about a specific browser (FF, Chromium etc) but the generic browser button.

Comment: are you talking about icons on home screen maybe? just drag&drop the icon from apps

Comment: @alecxs: Home screen. Although actually it's on the button row that persists even when I scroll to additional screens with app icons.

Comment: anyway it's drag&drop too